# Can we have nested 'A' tags in html

Tags: html

My html code is as follows.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <body>
            <a href="http://www.w3schools.com">w3schools
            <a href="http://www.google.com">google</a>
            some text
            <span>span text</span>
            </a>
        </body>
    </html>
```

But outcome looks as shown below

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <a href="http://www.w3schools.com">
        w3schools
        </a><a href="http://www.google.com">google</a>
        some text
        <span>span text</span>
        enter code here
    </body>
</html>
```

Is this really allowed to nest like this.

Comment: You are not allowed to nest `<a>` tags like you want.  Why do you want to do that?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.2

Comment: What if there is a 'A' tag already present (as i explained above) that has plenty of dom elements defined under it. so now if i want to navigate to some other page when a certain part of the nested dom is clicked.

Comment: No, anchor tags can't be nested. Period. It's invalid HTML. Besides, how would that even work?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Friend Your question is little bit confusing, but first of all, nested `<a>` tags will not display expected results. You can try using list tags.

May be this will work for you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <ul><a href="http://www.w3schools.com">
                <li>w3schools</li>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="http://www.google.com">google</a></li>
                    </ul>
        </ul>
        some text
        <span>span text</span>
        </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You *cannot* [nest `<a>` tags](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.2).

I'm not quite sure why you would want to do that: if you're looking to make parts of a sentence or word link to different things, you *can*, but that's not how it's done: you simple wrap the parts that you are referring to in the tags, which is basic HTML style:

[This](//stackoverflow.com) [is](//meta.stackoverflow.com) [a](//meta.stackexchange.com) [t](//stackexchange.com)[e](//example.com)[st](//google.com):

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">This</a> <a href="http://meta.stackoverflow.com">is</a> <a href="http://meta.stackexchange.com">a</a> <a href="http://stackexchange.com">t</a><a href="http://example.com">e</a><a href="http://google.com">st</a>
```